# Indicator shows different data if I change timeframes

Tags: pine-script

I am new on PineScript and I am trying to create an indicator to show me the trend in different timezones on a table, but I have an issue.

Example. If I am on a 1 hour chart the trend is showed bullish,if I change the chart to 15 minutes it shows bearish, and so on. Can someone help me to find out why is not showing the same trend no matter I change the timeframe?

```
ema_1m = ta.ema(close, 9)
ema_15m = ta.ema(close, 9)
ema_1H = ta.ema(close, 9)
ema_4H = ta.ema(close, 9)


ema_1m_tf = input.timeframe("1")
ema_15m_tf = input.timeframe("15")
ema_1H_tf = input.timeframe("60")
ema_4H_tf = input.timeframe("240")

ema_1m_s = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, ema_1m_tf, ema_1m, gaps = barmerge.gaps_on)
ema_15m_s = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, ema_15m_tf, ema_15m, gaps = barmerge.gaps_on)
ema_1H_s = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, ema_1H_tf, ema_1H, gaps = barmerge.gaps_on)
ema_4H_s = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, ema_4H_tf, ema_4H, gaps = barmerge.gaps_on)

var table myTable = table.new(position.top_right, 9, 2, border_width = 1)

if barstate.islast
    tf1 = "1m"
    tf2 = "15m"
    tf3 = "1H"
    tf4 = "4H"
    table.cell(myTable, 0, 0, text = tf1, bgcolor = color.black, text_color = color.white)
    table.cell(myTable, 1, 0, text = tf2, bgcolor = color.black, text_color = color.white)
    table.cell(myTable, 2, 0, text = tf3, bgcolor = color.black, text_color = color.white)
    table.cell(myTable, 3, 0, text = tf4, bgcolor = color.black, text_color = color.white)
    
    table.cell(myTable, 0, 1, bgcolor = (close > ema_1m_s ? color.green : color.red), text_color = color.white)   
    table.cell(myTable, 1, 1, bgcolor = (close > ema_15m_s ? color.green : color.red), text_color = color.white)
    table.cell(myTable, 2, 1, bgcolor = (close > ema_1H_s ? color.green : color.red), text_color = color.white)
    table.cell(myTable, 3, 1, bgcolor = (close > ema_4H_s ? color.green : color.red), text_color = color.white)
```

Answer (score 0):

Requesting data from the lower timeframes are not recommended and not supported with the `request.security()` function.

Check out the newly published [request.security_lower_tf()](https://www.tradingview.com/blog/en/request-more-data-from-your-scripts-31944/) function.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have been reading and trying to update my script but it is not working. I don't understand how to use request.security_lower_tf(). Do you have any examples?